# Invalid Placeholder error while HttpResponseMessage content

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, xunit

I am writing an unit test and have to return response object. I was able to to return below response

```
var res = new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Content = new StringContent(string.Format("{{ 'email':'{0}', 'first_name':'{1}', 'last_name':'{2}', 'id':'{3}' }}", data.Email, data.FirstName, data.LastName, data.Id))
            };
```

but now need to wrap all response in 'data' property. For this updated code like below

```
var res = new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Content = new StringContent(string.Format("{{'data':{'email':'{0}','first_name':'{1}','last_name':'{2}','id':'{3}'}}}", data.Email, data.FirstName, data.LastName, data.Id))
            };
```

but getting below error

Message: 
    System.FormatException : Input string was not in a correct format.
  Stack Trace: 
    StringBuilder.FormatError()
    StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
    String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
    String.Format(String format, Object[] args)

[image]

Not sure whats wrong here. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried lot of options and ended with below.

```
string.Format("{{ 'data': {{ 'email':'{0}', 'first_name':'{1}', 'last_name':'{2}', 'id':'{3}' }} }}", data.Email, data.FirstName, data.LastName, data.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use Newtonsoft.Json

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         var data = new
        {
            email = "data@ada.com",
            first_name = "abc",
            last_name = "abc",
            id = 1
        };

        var data1 = new {data};
        var s = new JsonSerializer();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (var w = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            s.Serialize(w, data1);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You have used newtonsoft json ? You will direct get the content to post there will be no string builder .how can be same error ?

Comment: I need to return string content as response, string that Newtonsoft generating will not work. I am usingg JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to parse in class object.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have much time to look but can you try this ?

```
var res = new HttpResponseMessage()
{
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
    Content = new StringContent(string.Format("{{'data':{'email':'{0}','first_name':'{1}','last_name':'{2}','id':'{3}'}}}", data.data.Email, data.data.FirstName, data.data.LastName, data.data.Id))
};
```

Comment: you were close. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is string forma exception. You can repair your text. you should try the possibilities. Maybe this works "  data.data[Email], data.data[FirstName], data.data[LastName], data.data[Id ]".

Answer (score 0):

If you are avoiding serializing, you can use c# 7.0 feature $ string interpolation.
Use:

```
var res = new HttpResponseMessage()
{
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
    Content = new StringContent($"{{ 'data': {{ 'email':'{data.Email}', 'first_name':'{data.FirstName}', 'last_name':'{data.LastName}', 'id':'{data.Id}' }} }}")
};
```